# Moving queue data to the head of another queue

Tags: redis

I want to empty a queue into another queue. I assumed that `RPOPLPUSH` would be the tool for me, running it until queue exhaustion. I want to do this in an atomic step, so I thought that a Lua script would be the tool for me.

Unfortunately the script I wrote is not working. Instead it looks stuck in an infinite loop and triggers a BUSY error after timeout. This is the code:

```lua
local x
if KEYS[1] == KEYS[2] then
    return
end
repeat
    x = redis.call('rpoplpush', KEYS[1], KEYS[2])
until not x
```

And this is the Python client code I use to execute it:

```python
script = """
...same script as above...
"""
redis.eval(script, 2, 'source_queue', 'dest_queue')
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the script - it runs perfectly ok on my local Redis. An infinite loop will trigger the BUSY response from Redis after the defined `lua-time-limit` - is that the behavior that you're seeing?

Comment: @ItamarHaber yes, I can confirm, that's the behavior. Regardless of whether source_queue had data in it or was empty

Answer (score 1):

The condition in `until` is wrong. If `rpoplpush` executed on empty source list it return `nil` and `until not x` produce infinite loop. Try this:

```
if KEYS[1] == KEYS[2] then
    return
end
local x
repeat
    x = redis.call('rpoplpush', KEYS[1], KEYS[2])
until x ~= nil
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right. Calling `rpoplpush` returns `false` on an empty source list.

Comment: This is Lua script, executed in Redis throw eval command. It return `nil` if source list is empty.

Comment: What does this return for you? I'm running Redis 3.0.
`r.eval("""if redis.call('rpoplpush', 'empty_queue', 'emtpy_queue') == nil then return 'this is nil' else return 'this is not nil' end""", 0)`